# JavaFX java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException issue PROJECT SETUP ISSUE

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, java.lang.class

Hello I am new in JavaFx, I'm trying to build a login/signup application, I think my code is correct and my big issue is a NULL statement or a project setup that I can't see to fix. I tried to follow most of the answers in similar questions but I understand I don't have the same issue. Don't mind the italian comments and thank you in advance and kind regards.

Here's the error window I get, as a beginner I got a bit overwhelmed, what seems to be the issue in the main? I'll also include an image of my project setup

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at com.example.loginsignup/com.example.loginsignup.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.loginsignup.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my Controller

```
package com.example.loginsignup;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable { //controller per pulsanti login e signup


    @FXML
    private TextField tf_username;

    @FXML
    private TextField tf_password;

    @FXML
    private Button button_login;

    @FXML
    private Button button_signup;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) { //richiamo metodi per il pulsante di login
        button_login.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                DBUtil.logInUser(actionEvent, tf_username.getText(), tf_password.getText()); //passo tutto da DBUtil per il login
            }
        });

        button_signup.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                DBUtil.changeScene(actionEvent,"signup.fxml", "Sign Up", "null");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here's my main

```
package com.example.loginsignup;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root;
        root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")));
        stage.setTitle("Log in");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        stage.show(); //1:14:24

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the sample.fxml as the front page, I did not put my login and signup controller, DBcontroller nor their respective .fxml files as they are correct

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="60.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@DominatorLogo.jpg" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="446.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="78.0" layoutY="104.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Username">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="78.0" layoutY="237.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Password">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="tf_username" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="113.0" promptText="username" />
            <TextField fx:id="tf_password" layoutX="234.0" layoutY="247.0" promptText="password" />
            <Button fx:id="button_login" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="326.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Log in" />
            <Label layoutX="70.0" layoutY="369.0" text="Not a User?" />
            <Button fx:id="button_signup" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="364.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Sign up" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Here's the project setup:

[image: setup]

Comment: Your FXML files (and other resources, such as images) need to go in the package under resources, not under java (they are not Java source code).

Comment: Your fxml is called “hello-view.fxml”, but you are looking for a non existent resource “sample.fxml”.

Comment: @James_D  Thank you, It really did work, now it loads my fxml file!